# OAuth Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, oauth, oauth-2.0

My english is not very good.

In MVC, for the OAuth session, we place the **[Autorize]** attribute per method.

I do not use simple membership and I have my own membership system. Is the **[Authorize]** attribute used ***for membership or for OAuth 2.0***?

Do you have an idea on this? If we do not use Microsoft Simple Membership, **can we use OAuth 2.0 in our project**?

I offer my thanks.

Ayşe

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is an open standard for authorization. OAuth provides client applications a "secure delegated access" to server resources on behalf of a resource owner

using OAuth 2.0,  enable login by the users using their social accounts like Facebook, Twitter, Google etc.
We can do this using OAuth 2.0. Using this account credentials users can login to the application. Because many users use various accounts.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I voted favorably for you. I want to create a new user with this information after I have received the required token. I don't want to register at Microsoft simple membership. What information do I know that is being verified? I do not use Microsoft simple membership. I will use OAuth 2.0 on my own membership system. What information do I use to compare and understand the authorization? Thank you so much.